# Login failed for user in MVC application

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Hello I am trying to make a user authentication page, I added to my web.config something like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/User/Login" timeout="2880">

  </forms>

</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" />
```

[image: I connect to database with sqlauthentication mode like u can see in Server Explorer but when i trying to start application i have error.]

I connect to database with sqlauthentication mode like you can see in Server Explorer but when I try to start the application I get an error.

Here is my connection string to:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=db-mssql;Initial Catalog=inzS9776;Persist Security Info=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: try adding:  integrated security=True;    to your conn string